# Devise breaks when resetting password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise and I thought everything was working, until I tred to reset a password.  I get the error below.  Devise can't find a template called layout/email.  Why does it even want that?  I was under the impression that after the form posted, devise would redirect to the user sign in page.

I suspect that devise is having trouble finding the "reset_password_instructions.html.haml" file, since it's clearly able to generate the reset token, but no email is actually sent.  Based on the error message below, does that sound like the correct diagnosis?

What I do I have to do to fix this?  I'm guessing I'll have to modify devise by overwriting a controller, but I'm not sure.  Any suggestions?

```
Started POST "/users/password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-06 05:52:42 -0500
    Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kGvuZiu+iu1HAx9xf4RsISj2SM410uLRoR6RbiJcBQw=", "user"=>{"email"=>"test1@example.com"}, "commit"=>"Send me reset password instructions"}
      User Load (6.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'test1@example.com' LIMIT 1
      User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."reset_password_token" = '5QZVFAsq2ev22gpQfe9i' LIMIT 1
       (0.1ms)  BEGIN
       (3.0ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "reset_password_token" = '5QZVFAsq2ev22gpQfe9i', "reset_password_sent_at" = '2012-08-06 10:52:42.591763', "updated_at" = '2012-08-06 10:52:42.593474' WHERE "users"."id" = 2
       (0.5ms)  COMMIT
    DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a template handler in the template name is deprecated. You can simply remove the handler name or pass render :handlers => [:haml] instead. (called from call at /Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/sass-3.1.19/lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54)
    DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a template handler in the template name is deprecated. You can simply remove the handler name or pass render :handlers => [:haml] instead. (called from call at /Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/sass-3.1.19/lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54)
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 113ms

    ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template layouts/email with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
      * "/Users/bendowney/Sites/RobotimusApp/app/views"
      * "/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@RobotimusApp/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/views"
    ):
      actionpack (3.2.5) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:58:in `find'
      actionpack (3.2.5) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:109:in `find'
      actionpack (3.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:3:in `find_template'
      actionpack (3.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:79:in `resolve_layout'
      actionpack (3.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:86:in `resolve_layout'
      actionpack (3.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:69:in `block in find_layout'
      actionpack (3.2.5) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:228:in `with_layout_format'
#...etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devise sends an email with a reset token before redirecting the user. Sending emails also requires templates and layouts. In your case, this step fails because somewhere in your code, you probably specify `layout 'email'` for an ActionMailer class but didn't actually create this layout template.

Try adding a file `app/views/layouts/email.html.haml` that at a minimum contains this:

```
= yield
```

(or `<%= yield %>` in an .html.erb template).

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem.  (Though for some reason, I couldn't actually just have an empty file.  I needed to fill it out as in a bit, as if it were the email equivalent of layout/application.html.)

Comment: Of course, thanks for pointing that out - I edited my answer accordingly.